# How to distinguish drop from drag abort

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

When an HTML5 drag operation ends over another window, a `Drop` event fires in the target window and a `DragEnd` event fires on the dragged element in the source window.

For both copy and move, the drop target will perform a copy operation using the data carried by `e.dataTransfer`, and for the move operation the item must be removed in the source window.

When the event fires in the source window, how should the `DragEnd` handler determine whether the operation culminated in a drop or was aborted?

It is not enough to know whether a copy or cut operation is underway; a cut operation removes the item from the source only when it succeeds at the destination. It is, if you like, transactional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an [answer in mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API/Drag_operations#dragend). Follow the link and scroll down to the section **Finishing a drag**. Unfortunately this information is in neither the `DragEnd` nor the `DataTransfer` documentation pages.

> Once the drag is complete, a dragend event is fired at the source of the drag (the same element that received the dragstart event). This event will fire [whether] the drag was successful [or] cancelled. However, you can use the dropEffect property to determine what drop operation occurred.
>
> *If the dropEffect property has the value none during a dragend, then the drag was cancelled.* Otherwise, the effect specifies which operation was performed. The source can use this information after a move operation to remove the dragged item from the old location.

Emphasis and repairs to sentence structure and grammar are mine.

Safari 8 is completely broken. It always reports "none" as the drop effect in the drop event.